# How is raycasting implemented

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics, raycasting

I know what it's used for, I know what it does.

What I am essentially asking is what is the math/code behind how it works?

I'm aware that any custom implementation would likely be slower than an engines official implementation, I just am interested in how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're refering to how a game like Wolfenstein 3D uses raycasting?

Here is a nice explanation on what raycasting is, and how it's implemented:
https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html

Here is a summary of a raycasting implementation (taken from the above website, edited for clarity):

> The basic idea of raycasting is as follows: the map is a 2D square grid,
>   and each square can either be 0 (no wall), or a positive value (some wall).
>
> For every x-position of the screen (every vertical strip of the screen),
>   send out a ray that starts at the player location and points in the player's looking direction.
>   Let this ray move forward on the 2D map until it hits a map square that contains a wall.
>   If it collided with a wall, calculate the distance of the collision to the player, and use this distance to
>   calculate how high this wall has to be drawn on the screen. The further away the wall is,
>   the smaller it's on screen; the closer it is, the higher it appears to be.
>
> To find the first wall that a ray encounters on its way, start at the player's position, and each frame
>   check whether or not the ray collided with a wall. If it is colliding, then the loop can stop.
>   Calculate the distance, and draw the wall. If the ray position is not   colliding with a wall, you have to trace it further. To do this, add a   constant value to its position in the ray's direction. For this new  position, check again if it's colliding with a wall or not. Keep doing this until a wall is hit.